# Android - Free software for deleting duplicates on SD card

Tags: android, duplicate-files, memory-card

I have a bunch of pictures/videos on my smartphone. Although I moved them all to the SD card, so that I have enough space on the smartphone itself.

The problem is that I found I had a bunch of duplicates in there. Checking it manually is stupid. However, I tried different applications and none of them could handle it.

I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is that it's on the SD card. I don't have enough space to move it back to my smartphone, and in addition, I would have to do it again in the case of further duplicates.

I tried to do it through the computer as well. However, deleting duplicates on smartphone via computer is absurd in itself. And anyway, if I connect it via USB, the software designed for it can't work with it.

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: "*deleting duplicates on smartphone via computer is absurd in itself*" — Since the photos are on an SD card, would plugging the card directly into the computer remove the absurdity?

Comment: However, for that I would need the adapter, into which I insert the microSD and then into the USB. But unfortunately I don't have this reduction. And most importantly, I would have to disassemble the smartphone every time. And I don't have a model with a detachable back cover, but the one where a "pin" is inserted to slide out the SIM/SD "drawer".

Comment: Could you clarify the criteria for "duplicate files"? Is just the same file name, or same meta data, or same content, including larger/smaller sizes, etc. ?

Comment: I mean pictures/videos that have different name, size, resolution, but the content is identical (or almost identical)